# Set Hyperlink to a Variable- update variable all hyperlinks update

Tags: html, variables, hyperlink

I have a website where there is the same hyperlink(URL) shown on multiple pages and different locations.
How can I set the hyperlink to a variable, store that variable somewhere then when I need to change the URL all I need to do is update the variable resulting in all hyperlinks pointing to that variable updating as well. rather than manually changing the hyperlink on every location on the site?

Hope this makes sense,

please post answers using the following methods
1- HTML
2- JavaScript
3-JQuery
4- (something I forgot to add to list but is easy to implement)

Comment: Don't know if it is possible to do in a pure HTML. Instead, you can use JQuery in such way. Assume you have a `<div id="element">`: `var hyperLink = '<a href="http://google.com'>Google</a>"; var element = $('#element'); element.append(hyperLink);`.

Comment: append? that would replace the var hyperlink to the var element? I am not a web developer but got stuck with this task :\

Comment: It will add a hyperlink to the div

Comment: https://www.staticgen.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [**Document.links API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links) which makes accessing any `<a>` or `<area>` with a `href` attribute very easy.

```
 nodeList = document.links
```

#### Demo

```js
// Any URL
var url = `https://www.example.com/`;

// [Optional] Any text
var txt = `Example.com`;

// Reference all <a> in a NodeList called lnx
var lnx = document.links;

/* for each loop, add the url to href
|| and the text and the index number to the <a> contents (in
|| between the tags <a>...</a>). 
|| Also set each `<a>` style to act as a block
*/
for (let a = 0; a < lnx.length; a++) {

  lnx[a].href = url;
  
  // [Optional]
  lnx[a].textContent = txt +' '+ a;
  
  // [Optional]
  lnx[a].style.display = "block";

}
```

```html
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
<a href='url'>url</a>
```

Comment: What exactly *is your situation?* It was my understanding that you have links that you wish to dynamically change the url on the fly. This technique is simple, the least amount of code, and very fast. On each page, you should already have at least one JavaScript file that all of your pages point to. It is there that you would put the code into. After having done that all you would have to do is change the `var url='http://anythingUwant.com'` and every `<a>` you have on your site will be converted as you requested in your question. Did you click the blue button that says *"Run Code Snippet"?*